# How to add to the query formula the dynamic element

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was trying to find an answer to my question using the different examples, but I still struggle with the solution.
I have the 'orders' google-sheet that has the dates listed as columns with the data filled up below:
[list of dates in columns]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wyAs.png
What I want is to get the range from the 'orders' table filtered by the specified date only and other conditions. I used the formula:

```js
=query('orders'!A1:GU2000, "select A,DI,B,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M  where DI is not null and C='RAM'")
```

where DI is the index of the column of the date I need.
Since the date is changing dynamically, how can I replace this manually specified DI name of the column with the dynamic element that is determined automatically from the 'orders' list by value?
So, I need to get the link to the required column from the 'orders' table by the value=today() and put it somehow dynamically to the formula above.
I'm not an expert in google sheets, unfortunately, so if someone can help me, it will be really appreciated.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Comment: well, I have found a work-around solution by specifying the required column name and just referring to this cell in the formula https://take.ms/bkr7b. it is working, but I bet it should be possible to get the better solution, where the required column name is determined automatically by matching the date: https://take.ms/DY5hs

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({'orders'!A1:M2000, FILTER('orders'!A1:2000, 'orders'!1:1=TODAY())}, 
 "select Col1,Col14,Col2,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13  
  where Col14 is not null 
    and Col3='RAM'")
```

Comment: Tried, it gives an error. Still playing with the formulas.

Comment: @ОлесяВиноградова can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: yep, can you share your gmail?